# I have overriden the Save method in a model with force=False, how do I use factoryboy to mock the Django model?

Tags: django, factory-boy

For example, see the code below:

```
class Thing(Model):
    def save(force=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if not force:
             raise Exception("don't save!")
```

FactoryBoy calls model.get_or_create() which calls model.save(). Is there any way to create an instance of this model in FactoryBoy without modifying the save or get_or_create methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is a local instance of a Django model, you should use the [build strategy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#strategies). Also, the create strategy invokes `_create` [method](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Factory._create), which can be overwritten to meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior of `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory` is to call `MyModel.objects.create()`.

If the goal is only for a single call in one test, just use `MyModelFactory.build()`.

If the goal is to *never* call `create()`, set the following in your declaration:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
  class Meta:
    model = models.MyModel
    strategy = factory.BUILD_STRATEGY
```

This maps `MyModelFactory()` to `MyModelFactory.build()` instead of the `DjangoModelFactory` default, `MyModelFactory.create()`.